# JSON to formData Convertion in php

Tags: php, json

I want to convert the JSON data into FormData using php language. 
Is it possible?
if possible then what will the code in php for this?

```
var formData = window.jsonToFormData();
```

want to convert this into formData

Comment: Specify better what you want to do. [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) is a method that allows you to create
 new form to send it with `$.ajax(...);`. In php you receive `$_POST['key']`.

Answer (score -1):

If the JSON file is coming from a post request from the front-end there is a way to achieve the same result by grabbing the from and use FromData web API in Javascript.

Answer (score -1):

With this JSON:

```
{
"formName": "Registrierungsformular",
"description": "Bitte geben Sie ihre Daten an.",
"action": "submit-form.php",
"method": "POST",
"width": "500",
"height": "500",
"formData": [
    {
        "type": "section",
        "name": "basicSection",
        "label": "basic",
        "description": "Bitte geben Sie ihre Stamm-Daten an.",
        "fields": [
            {
                "type": "text",
                "name": "firstName",
                "label": "Vorname",
                "placeholder": "Geben Sie Ihren Vornamen ein",
                "required": true,
                "pattern": "^[a-zA-Z]+$"
            },
            {
                "type": "text",
                "name": "lastName",
                "label": "Nachname",
                "placeholder": "Geben Sie Ihren Nachnamen ein",
                "required": true,
                "pattern": "^[a-zA-Z]+$"
            },
            {
                "type": "email",
                "name": "email",
                "label": "E-Mail-Adresse",
                "placeholder": "Geben Sie Ihre E-Mail-Adresse ein",
                "required": true,
                "pattern": "^[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$"
            },
            {
                "type": "password",
                "name": "password",
                "label": "Passwort",
                "placeholder": "Geben Sie Ihr Passwort ein",
                "required": true,
                "pattern": "^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\\d)[a-zA-Z\\d]{8,}$",
                "description": "Das Passwort muss mindestens 8 Zeichen lang sein und muss mindestens einen Großbuchstaben, einen Kleinbuchstaben und eine Ziffer enthalten."
            },
            {
                "type": "option",
                "name": "gender",
                "label": "Geschlecht",
                "required": true,
                "options": [
                    {
                        "label": "Männlich",
                        "value": "male"
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "Weiblich",
                        "value": "female"
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "Divers",
                        "value": "diverse"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "type": "section",
        "name": "addressSection",
        "label": "Adresse",
        "description": "Bitte geben Sie ihre Adress-Daten an.",
        "fields": [
            {
                "type": "text",
                "name": "street",
                "label": "Straße",
                "placeholder": "Geben Sie Ihre Straße ein",
                "required": false
            },
            {
                "type": "text",
                "name": "houseNumber",
                "label": "Hausnummer",
                "placeholder": "Geben Sie Ihre Hausnummer ein",
                "required": true
            },
            {
                "type": "text",
                "name": "zipCode",
                "label": "PLZ",
                "placeholder": "Geben Sie Ihre PLZ ein",
                "required": true,
                "pattern": "^\\d{5}$"
            },
            {
                "type": "text",
                "name": "city",
                "label": "Stadt",
                "placeholder": "Geben Sie Ihre Stadt ein",
                "required": true
            },
            {
                "type": "checkbox",
                "name": "terms",
                "label": "Ich habe die Nutzungsbedingungen gelesen und akzeptiert",
                "required": true
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

Here is the Javascript, CSS and PHP code you can use:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var form = document.querySelector('form');
  form.style.width = '<?php echo $formData['width']; ?>px';
  form.style.height = '<?php echo $formData['height']; ?>px';
  form.style.overflow = 'auto';
};
```

```css
/* Schriftart und Größe */
body {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
}

/* Formular-Container */
form {
    max-width: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-align: center;
}

section {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

/* Überschrift */
h2 {
    font-size: 24px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}

/* Label-Texte */
label {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #333;
    text-align: left;
}

/* Texteingabefelder */
input[type="text"], input[type="email"], input[type="tel"], input[type="password"],
    textarea {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    text-align: left;
}

/* Select-Element */
select {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    text-align: left;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
}

/* Optionen im Select-Element */
option {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
}

/* Button */
button[type="submit"] {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
}

button[type="submit"]:hover {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
}

/* Pflichtfelder */
input[required], textarea[required] {
    border-color: #c1292e;
}

input[required]::placeholder, textarea[required]::placeholder {
    color: #c1292e;
}

/* Erfolgreiche Übermittlung */
form.successful {
    background-color: #d0e8c6;
}

form.successful h2 {
    color: #3c763d;
}

form.successful button[type="submit"] {
    background-color: #3c763d;
}

.centered {
    text-align: center;
}

label::before {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    margin-right: 8px; /* Abstand zwischen Checkbox und Text */
}

/* Scrollbar */
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
}

/* Track */
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background: #f1f1f1;
}

/* Thumb */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: #888;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

/* Button */
::-webkit-scrollbar-button {
    display: none;
}


ol {
  counter-reset: item;

  padding-left: 0;
}

ol li {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: .5rem;

}

ol li:before {
  content: counters(item, ".") ". ";
  counter-increment: item;
  color: #666;
  font-weight: bold;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Meine Formular-Seite</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $_GET["css"]; ?>">
</head>
<body>

<?php

$formData = json_decode(utf8_encode(file_get_contents($_GET["json"])), true);
?>

<form name="<?php echo $formData['formName']; ?>"
      action="<?php echo $formData['action']; ?>"
      method="<?php echo $formData['method']; ?>">
    <h1><?php echo $formData['formName']; ?></h1>
    <p><?php echo $formData['description']; ?></p>

    <?php foreach ($formData['formData'] as $section): ?>
        <section>
            <h2><?php echo $section['label']; ?></h2>
            <p><?php echo $section['description']; ?></p>

            <?php foreach ($section['fields'] as $field): ?>
                <?php if ($field['type'] !== 'section'): ?>
                    <div>
                        <label for="<?php echo $field['name']; ?>">
                            <?php echo $field['label']; ?>
                        </label>
                        <?php echo getFieldInput($field); ?>
                        <?php if ($field['description']): ?>
                            <p><?php echo $field['description']; ?></p>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </div>
                <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </section>
    <?php endforeach; ?>

    <button type="submit">Abschicken</button>
</form>

<?php
function getFieldInput($field) {
    switch ($field['type']) {
        case 'text':
        case 'email':
        case 'password':
            return '<input type="'.$field['type'].'"
                    name="'.$field['name'].'"
                    placeholder="'.$field['placeholder'].'"
                    '.($field['required'] ? " required " : '').'
                    '.($field['pattern'] ? ' pattern='.$field['pattern'] : '').'
                    '.($field['value'] ? 'value="' . $field['value'] . '"' : '').' />';
        case 'radio':
            $optionsHtml = '';
            foreach ($field['options'] as $option) {
                $optionsHtml .= '<div class="centered">
                                <input type="'.$field['type'].'"
                                       name="'.$field['name'].'"
                                       value="'.$option['value'].'"
                                       '.($field['required'] ? ' required ' : '').'
                                       '.($field['value'] === $option['value'] ? 'checked' : '').' />
                                <label for="'.$option['value'].'">'.$option['label'].'</label>
                            </div>';
            }
            return $optionsHtml;
        case 'option':
            $optionsHtml = '';
            foreach ($field['options'] as $option) {
                $optionsHtml .= '<option value="'.$option['value'].'">'.$option['label'].'</option>';
            }
            return '<select id="'.$field['name'].'" name="'.$field['name'].'">'.$optionsHtml.'</select>';
        case 'checkbox':
            return '<input type="'.$field['type'].'"
                    name="'.$field['name'].'"
                    '.($field['required'] ? ' required ' : '').' />';
        default:
            return '';
    }
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```